# NodeJS Variable Scope: Preventing accessing global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, global-variables

Let's say I got a global variable called myData. It was declared as `myData = 1;` at the beginning of a script.

Goal:

I want to create a single module that will not have access this `myData` in any way. `myData` must remain global in other modules.

Note: Yes, I already do know that I could require `myData` in every page where I need it but that's not what I'm looking for.

---

Attempts:

To do that, at the very beginning of the module, I wrote: `var myData;`. The module could no longer access `myData` directly by `myData`.

Problem: You can still access it via `GLOBAL.myData`

So I instead, I wrote `var myData, GLOBAL;` at the beginning of the module.

---

Are there any other ways someone could access `myData`? If so, how could I prevent it?

Comment: If not in strict mode: `(function(){this.myData})()`

Comment: You asked if there are any other ways someone could reach the global. The above is not the same as `exports.myData`. it is reaching the global variable.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was a way to prevent reaching `myData`. But yeah, you are right, with this code you can reach `myData`. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `this` related to `exports` is the global variable? Kinda like `global.exports.myData`?

Comment: In a module, `this` is referring to the `exports` object, which is not the global object. `GLOBAL` or `global` is a reference to the global object that is the single shared global that all modules can access. Like the `window` object in a browser.

Comment: ...there is no `global.exports` property.

Comment: Why are you using globals in the first place?

Comment: For example, `process` is a global variable. `process.exit()` will stop the application and I don't want coders to be able to access the global variable `process`.